# Bounty links are hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The CSS rules specify special colors for bounty boxes and links therein:

```
.bounty {
background-color: #FF9D5B!important;
}

.bounty a {
color: #D3293D;
}
```

However, especially without the help of bold, the two colors do not have enough contrast to make link text readable, and certainly don't help in making links stand out:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed.

Hyperlinks in bounty boxes are now a darker shade of red (`#69151F`, as [fredley suggested](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/bounty-links-are-hard-to-read/3189#3189)), and also bold.

```
.bounty a {
    color: #69151F;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a slightly darker red, perhaps #69151F?